# Min Width Table with one column filling remaning width?

Tags: html, css

I have a table which I don't want to have a width of less than 540 pixels, in this table I want a single column to fill the remaining width if the content is less than 540 pixels wide.

If I set this column to have width of 99% it works in Firefox, Safari and Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer (any version), where the table grows to the full page width.

I need this to work in IE7 and above.

edit:

added some code:

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="my-table">
        <tr>
            <td class="first"><img src="my-img.png"></td>
            <td class="expand">Some text here... should grow</td>
            <td class="meta">short text</td>
            <td class="end-col">final column</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    min-width: 540px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.expand {
    width: 99%;
}
```

.first, .meta and .end-col should all shrink wrap to their respective contents.

This works in everything but Internet Explorer.

Comment: Can you post the code you've got so far?

Comment: add the width to your table .my-table {width:540px;}